# how to create orders and order linelist in odoo using node js

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, odoo, odoo-10

I want to create orders and place the order-line to odoo db. But I can't create an order or an orderline list. I get the error `faultString: ('The requested operation ("create" on "Sales Order" (sale.order)) was rejected because of the following rules:\\n\\n\\n(Records: SO00078 (id=55), User: yuvaraj (id=14))', None)`.

I am using node js with handlebars and npm package 
https://www.npmjs.com/package/odoo-xmlrpc

```
odoo.connect(function(err){
    if(err){
        return res.render('placed_order',{error:"oodo connection problem !"})
    }
    else{
        var inParams = [];
        inParams.push({
            'partner_id': 36,
            'company_id':"1",
            "date_order":'2020-05-13 07:41:45',
            "warehouse_id":  "1" ,
            'user_id':17,
            'state':'sale',
            'note':'sale',
            "pricelist_id": "1",
            "currency_id":  'INR' ,
            'expected_date': '2020-05-19 07:41:45',
        });
        var params = [];
        params.push(inParams);

        odoo.execute_kw('sale.order','create',params,function(err,order){
            if(err){
                console.log(err,"No order created")
            }
            else{
                var inParams1 = [];
                inParams1.push({
                    "product_uom":"1",
                    "product_id": "1",
                    "product_qty":"1",              
                    "order_id":order,
                    "price_unit":"2999",
                    "amount_total":"2999"
                })

                var params1 = [];
                params1.push(inParams1);
                console.log(params1,"params1")
                odoo.execute_kw('sale.order.line','create',params1,function(error,line){
                    if(error){
                        console.log("No order line created",error)
                    }
                    res.redirect('thanks?order_id='+order)
                })
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Can you create sale orders with your user "yuvaraj" (id=14) if you log in to odoo with it and create a sale order manually?

Answer (score 0):

I think odoo's security rule has given this error,

because you do not have rights to create order.

Check rule's domain and give the correct rights to your user (Yuvaraj).